# Cubic symmetry and a stiffness tensor

Tags: classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, tensor-calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stiffness tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45802/stiffness-tensor)

Let's have a stiffness tensor:

$$ 
a^{ijkl}: a^{ijkl} = a^{jikl} = a^{klij} = a^{ijlk}.
$$

It has a 21 independent components for an anisotropic body.

How does body symmetry (cubic, hexagonal etc.) change the number of independent components of the tensor? For example, for cubiс symmetry it has three components. How to explain it?

Update.

Is the explanation a simple realization of idea
$$
a_{ijkl}' = \beta_{im}a^{m}\beta_{jt}a^{t}\beta_{k f}a^{f}\beta_{ld}a^{d} = a_{ijkl},
$$ 
where $\beta_{\alpha \beta}$ is a components of a matrix $\beta$ for rotation around z-, x-, y-axis at the same time?

Comment: Well, it's not a "simple realization" of the idea. You need to solve a math problem. But you surely need to know how tensors transform under transformations, indeed. You have to find all the linearly independent 4-index tensors that are invariant under all the elements in the discrete body symmetry. For example, for the cubic one, only $\delta^{ij}\delta^{kl}$, $\delta^{ik}\delta^{il}+(k\leftrightarrow l)$, and "$\delta^{ijkl}$" which is only one if all indices agree survive.

Comment: Same question by OP on [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248357/question-about-stiffness-tensor) and exact duplicate [on this site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45802/stiffness-tensor).

Comment: Unless I am much mistaken, this is effectively a duplicate of your earlier question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45802/520 . The way to respond to a question which did not recieve as much attention as you hoped is not by re-posting, but by [bringing more attention to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/2509).

Comment: I don't understand how do you proceed to the consideration of Kronecker symbols. Can you help to understand it?

Comment: Privět, Maxim. I immediately see the answer involving Kronecker symbols – and the special "four-index Kronecker which is not a real Kronecker" – because I know that these tensors constructed out of the Kronecker symbols are invariant under all $O(3)$ rotations, so they must also be invariant under the cubic crystal's symmetries. Except for the allowed "four-index Kronecker" contribution, the cubic symmetry is almost as constraining as the full rotational symmetry. It's straightforward to prove these things but you must understand group theory a bit.

Comment: Thank you.
And where can I read about it (I'm about "...tensors constructed out of the Kronecker symbols are invariant under all O(3) rotations...")?

Comment: Oh, I understood the next words, "...I know that these tensors constructed out of the Kronecker symbols are invariant under all O(3) rotations...".

For proving it there is enough to show the invariance of $\delta_{ij}$:

$$
\delta_{ij}' = R_{ik}R_{jm}\delta^{km} = R_{im}R^{m}_{j} = |\mathbf R \mathbf R ^{T}|_{ij} = |\mathbf E|_{ij} = \delta_{ij}. 
$$
Other combinations are also invariant.

Comment: But how to explain your summand "four-index Kronecker"?